# What's the most effective way to clean dusty builds?

Tags: cleaning

I have a large airplane build that I haven't touched in quite a while, and it has built up quite a large amount of dust. I've tried using a wet washcloth to wipe off the dust, but when cleaning that way I can accidentally break off large chunks of the build. So, how can I clean off dust in the most efficient way?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to LEGO Answers - I think you'll find the answer to your question here: [Cleaning between the studs](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1435/) :)